# Professor at MIT needs an AP!

Tags: code-golf, card-games

The 5-card magic trick involves a magician whose assistant gives them 4 shown cards and a hidden one, in this order, and the magician must guess the hidden one.

## WARNING: Solution below! Leave now or get spoiled with it.

---

#### The solution

The trick here is that the five cards are given *in a specific order*!

\$c_1,...,c_5\$ are the 5 cards in the given order.

\$x_n\$ is the card number of \$c_n\$ in \$NO=[\text{A,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,T,J,Q,K}]\$ (number order).

\$a+b\$, where \$a\$ is a card number and \$b\$ is an integer, is equal to the card number \$b\$ steps to the right of \$a\$ in \$NO\$, wrapping to the beginning if necessary.

\$s_n\$ is the suit of \$c_n\$ in \$SO=[\clubsuit,\diamondsuit,\heartsuit,\spadesuit]\$ (suit order).

\$a\circ b\$, where \$a\$ is a card number and \$b\$ is a suit, denotes the card with card number \$a\$ and suit \$b\$.

\$a<b\$, where \$a\$ and \$b\$ are cards, is true if \$a\$'s suit is to the left of \$b\$'s suit in \$SO\$, or their suits are equal and \$a\$'s card number is to the left of \$b\$'s card number in \$NO\$.

\$a>b\$, where \$a\$ and \$b\$ are cards, is true if \$a<b\$ is false.

\$PI(a,b,c)\$, where \$a\$, \$b\$ and \$c\$ are cards, is the permutation index of this ordering of them, specified by the table below:
\$\begin{array}{|c|c|}\hline\text{Comparison}&PI(a,b,c)\\\hline a<b<c&1\\\hline a<b>c>a&2\\\hline a>b<c>a&3\\\hline a<b>c<a&4\\\hline a>b<c<a&5\\\hline a>b>c&6\\\hline\end{array}\$

The solution to the 5-card magic trick is problem is:$$c_5=(x_1+PI(c_2,c_3,c_4))\circ s_1$$

#### The challenge

So far, so good. However, doing the computation specified above is already asked for [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/165390/41024). Instead, your challenge is, given the 5 cards in no specific order, to order them properly. This means that the first four cards in the output will represent the fifth. In other words, be the assistant. Requirements:

- \$s_5=s_1\$.
- \$x_5=x_1+PI(c_2,c_3,c_4)\$ (that is, this must be possible).

#### Example

Let's consider the set `7H,2D,6D,5C,6C`. First of all, we take the 25 pairs:

```
7H,7H 7H,2D 7H,6D 7H,5C 7H,6C
2D,7H 2D,2D 2D,6D 2D,5C 2D,6C
6D,7H 6D,2D 6D,6D 6D,5C 6D,6C
5C,7H 5C,2D 5C,6D 5C,5C 5C,6C
6C,7H 6C,2D 6C,6D 6C,5C 6C,6C
```

Then, we obviously remove the 5 pairs that contain the same card twice, they don't exist in a single deck:

```
      7H,2D 7H,6D 7H,5C 7H,6C
2D,7H       2D,6D 2D,5C 2D,6C
6D,7H 6D,2D       6D,5C 6D,6C
5C,7H 5C,2D 5C,6D       5C,6C
6C,7H 6C,2D 6C,6D 6C,5C
```

Afterwards, since the suits must be the same, different suits in a pair is a no-no:

```
                             
            2D,6D            
      6D,2D                  
                        5C,6C
                  6C,5C
```

Finally, we check if it's possible to get from the first card to the second by adding at most 6, removing half of the remaining pairs:

```
                             
            2D,6D            
                             
                        5C,6C
```

Now we have the valid pairs: `2D,6D` and `5C,6C`. The first card of each pair is card 1, while the last is card 5.

We're going to go with `5C,6C` here for easiness. The whole set is `7H,2D,6D,5C,6C`, so, removing the 2 cards in the pair we've chosen, we have `7H,2D,6D`. These cards will represent `6 - 5 = 1`, so we have to order them like "min, mid, max". `7H > 2D < 6D < 7H`, or simply `2D < 6D < 7H`, so we now have `2D,6D,7H`.

The last step is to put all of this together, so our result will be `5C,2D,6D,7H,6C`.

#### Clarifications

- You may use `10` instead of `T`.
- You may use one of `♠♥♦♣`, `♤♡♢♧` or `♠♡♢♣` instead of `CDHS`, respectively.
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), the shortest code wins.

#### Test cases

You can output one or more of the valid solutions included for each test case.

```
8S,TD,5C,QS,TS -> 8S,5C,QS,TD,TS
              ... 8S,TD,TS,5C,QS
              ... TS,5C,8S,TD,QS

JD,KH,4S,9D,8S -> 9D,KH,8S,4S,JD
              ... 4S,JD,KH,9D,8S

4H,4D,TH,KH,2C -> 4H,KH,4D,2C,TH
              ... TH,4D,2C,4H,KH
              ... KH,4D,TH,2C,4H

3S,KS,8S,KH,9H -> 9H,8S,KS,3S,KH
              ... 3S,KS,9H,KH,8S
              ... 8S,3S,9H,KH,KS
              ... KS,KH,9H,8S,3S

KH,TS,3C,7H,JD -> 7H,TS,JD,3C,KH

4C,KC,TD,JD,QS -> KC,JD,QS,TD,4C
              ... TD,4C,KC,QS,JD

AC,5H,8D,6D,8S -> 6D,AC,8S,5H,8D

AS,TC,3S,2H,9C -> 9C,2H,AS,3S,TC
              ... AS,9C,2H,TC,3S

4C,JS,AS,8H,JC -> JC,JS,AS,8H,4C
              ... JS,JC,4C,8H,AS

4H,QS,TH,QC,AC -> QC,4H,QS,TH,AC
              ... 4H,QS,QC,AC,TH
```

Comment: It might be easier to visualize the permutations [by adding an _Example_ column](https://pastebin.com/E24UmCzi).

Comment: [magic - A five card trick - How does it work? - Puzzling Stack Exchange](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/6569/a-five-card-trick-how-does-it-work)

Comment: How lenient is input? Are tuples of card number and house instead of length-2 strings acceptable?

Comment: @Οurous That's not specified in the challenge; as long as it's reasonable (in your case, that seems reasonable enough), it's allowed.

Answer (score 3):

## [Node.js](https://nodejs.org), <s>190</s> <s>186</s> 180 bytes

```javascript
f=(a,p,g=c=>"A23456789TJQK".search(c[0])+10,[A,B,C,D,E]=a.sort(_=>p>>i++&1,i=0))=>A[k=1]!=E[1]|[B,C,D].sort((a,b)=>k=k*2|a[1]+g(a)>b[1]+g(b))|(k^4)%6+1-(g(E)-g(A)+13)%13?f(a,-~p):a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVJNj9pADL33V9BIW2WKYckXJJWSKp0gjZJTNLlFaRUoUMpqg2DVE9q/Tm0PRGrDZWS/Gb9nP8/v9k97Xp/2x7fJa/dzc71uY7uFI@zidZxYqev5wXwRRlVeFtb0vGlP61/2up41YuzMoE7hG0jIYNnE7fTcnd7sH3FyTJL9ePzJgX08EyJO0voQO83HeFk7zaXmgsY8RqUVPjjEh8/upcXr8c5uRbIy0UqIi3347oun@diZ2Dt7KSY7O0VlTzw53tctlk/ej@JLe113r@fuZTN96Xb21q6tUFtgVRkegcSj5FRbjRCj5@dRqCGQUGqoMqj0qDsRwrHBCTGxwUv94X@BnLgLhYdP3BGlYS8QZVAoKvY15BnRcUAgXoVDOp@ZiKRSd2JX3ul8RZV@Bq6ESnF395SvCDEPEGdwIOBRl4U2Xd4EItX3y80WGjx9o/M4jZSZ42aRd0cKRgrNA3GtN5yJNSpS82gHC0rRtpvkQpHd6IknkWVoCJUU8r5Ftrvs/S0kVZoF@pINoQAK3mqeDehSYgqog5CY5v@ua55ByrsOcJYHxfx7iIFddNm7fjmRBFdByu5U3AvGBqzkI194tJyYmDhkX3q6HEfTRBeq22iYIojThSTz@OuYD84Rsac9XclfhJzCYqYzKeIpfabrXw)

### How?

#### Identifying and comparing the card numbers

The helper function \$g\$ returns an index representing the number of a given card.

```javascript
g = c => "A23456789TJQK".search(c[0]) + 10
```

We add \$10\$ to force two digits for all entries, so that these indices can be safely sorted in lexicographical order. Therefore an Ace is \$10\$ and a King is \$22\$.

Given 2 cards \$a\$ and \$b\$ in `"NS"` format, we can compare them by suit first and number second with:

```javascript
a[1] + g(a) > b[1] + g(b)
```

#### Generating the permutations of the input

We recursively try all \$120\$ possible permutations of the input array \$a\$ by successively sorting it with different permutation seeds \$p\$. The cards are separately loaded into \$A\$, \$B\$, \$C\$, \$D\$ and \$E\$.

```javascript
[A, B, C, D, E] = a.sort(_ => p >> i++ & 1, i = 0)
```

[This code](https://tio.run/##TYzNqsIwFIT3eYpZNSnpLeo2pqD3uu0LiEiwUeLPiaS9gkifvZ64cnGGw8w3c3YP1x9SuA8/FDs/TQ4WW8iVrCDXWX6z/GXZSOyMEMeYVMsU8c0q3H268fcaDVosMV/MDEjrEi8BhMwYflzdxzSoPWzDxaZB0BoF5mUOL/7JnKvPMZCS8uPl2S0HO1hr8U@dPwbyHYoCqtW6@gZAXBmFOETq49XX13hSBA2JMPjkhsB@Xv3Oc7000/QG) shows when each permutation is first encountered. It takes \$699\$ iterations to try all of them.

#### Testing the suits

The first obvious test is to make sure that the first and last cards are of the same suit. We reject the permutation if they're not equal.

```javascript
A[k = 1] != E[1] // we also initialize k, which is used right after that
```

#### Testing the distance

We compute the distance between the first card number and the last card number with:

```javascript
(g(E) - g(A) + 13) % 13
```

Now comes the most tricky part. We have to test whether the order of the 3 other cards (\$B\$, \$C\$ and \$D\$) correctly describes this distance.

This test relies on the way the `sort()` algorithm of Node.js is working.

Assuming that the callback function of `sort()` is always returning a positive integer, Node.js will sort the array \$[A,B,C]\$ by applying these 3 steps:

1. compare \$A\$ with \$B\$
2. compare \$A\$ with \$C\$
3. compare \$B\$ with \$C\$

Let's consider the following code:

```javascript
[1, 2, 3].sort((a, b) => k = k * 2 | (a > b), k = 1)
```

We have \$A<B\$ (\$1<2\$), \$A<C\$ (\$1<3\$) and \$B<C\$ (\$2<3\$). All comparisons processed in the callback function are falsy and \$k\$ is simply multiplied by \$2^3\$. So, we end up with \$k=8\$.

Now, if we do:

```javascript
[3, 2, 1].sort((a, b) => k = k * 2 | (a > b), k = 1)
```

All comparisons are now thruthy, which generates the bitmask \$k=15\$.

Each permutation generates a unique bitmask, which is mapped to a unique distance:

```
 A, B, C | A>B | A>C | B>C | k  | distance
---------+-----+-----+-----+----+----------
 1, 2, 3 |  0  |  0  |  0  |  8 |    1
 1, 3, 2 |  0  |  0  |  1  |  9 |    2
 2, 1, 3 |  1  |  0  |  0  | 12 |    3
 2, 3, 1 |  0  |  1  |  1  | 11 |    4
 3, 1, 2 |  1  |  1  |  0  | 14 |    5
 3, 2, 1 |  1  |  1  |  1  | 15 |    6
```

Given \$k\$, we can convert it to the distance by doing:

$$d=((k\operatorname{xor}4)\bmod 6)+1$$

```
  k | xor 4 | mod 6 | +1
----+-------+-------+----
  8 |   12  |   0   |  1
  9 |   13  |   1   |  2
 12 |    8  |   2   |  3
 11 |   15  |   3   |  4
 14 |   10  |   4   |  5
 15 |   11  |   5   |  6
```

Putting everything together, we have the following test:

```javascript
[B, C, D]
.sort((a, b) =>
  k = k * 2 | a[1] + g(a) > b[1] + g(b)
)
| (k ^ 4) % 6 + 1
- (g(E) - g(A) + 13) % 13
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/),  <s>260 248</s>  232 bytes

```python
N="A23456789TJQK".find
D=lambda x,y="KC":(N(y[0])+~N(x[0]))%13+15*abs(ord(x[1])-ord(y[1]))
def f(l):a,e,b,c,d=[[x,y]+sorted({*l}-{x,y},key=D)for x in l for y in l if D(x,y)<6][0];print(a,*map(eval,"bbccddcdbdbcdcdbcb"[D(a,e)::6]),e)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VZDBjoIwEIbvPkXTZJNW62YVQWCXA4GDkcSEyI1waClkySIYNBuJcV@d7VQx8dL@M9/M/NMe@/N32xjDsPOwvzRWprW2nWQbR/i9rBo5Cb2aH4Tk6MJ6D0cBdsmO9OlHRmd/O3IBQd8WxmxhTrk4kbaTKrnI6BxUD4pOZFGiktTU5axgguVMemmq5mWzU9udC0mu0/o2v6rMjf0UvRfSsu3QBVUNqhHI/i6rEoVEVdEvK1PGn8euas6Es@mBH0nxy2uGhchzKXMppMjhygVOQ1VSUNe1MqruoSQptveY4SRUhxmoI9bhHmd0AnQLINqoYwXAgdB@0pUGkEs2Y90yGKkBHdH@3vGgzmakOkwAGOC7hlC5jZMhFwXjanqN@OnrAzChwwZgvW7l6ydAid5gqX2Dl8lbALrO1r7By4vuf6AVFPtAh38)

*-12 bytes thanks to Eric the Outgolfer*
*-14 bytes by removing a list comprehension*

Answer (score 1):

## [Clean](https://github.com/Ourous/curated-clean-linux), <s>225</s> <s>220</s> 209 bytes

```
import StdEnv,Data.List
n=['A23456789TJQK':n]
```

```
filter(\[[x,s],b,c,d,e]#[p,q,r:_]=map snd(sort(zip2[(elemIndices a n,b)\\[a,b]<-[b,c,d]][1..]))
=[snd(span((<>)x)n)!!(p+if(p>q)0if(q<r)(q+r)q),s]==e)o permutations
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PY5fS8MwFMXf9ykyfEjCsqJz6jbagVDB/XlQ6lsa5LZNJdCkaZLJ9MOvlg58Or977r2HUzYSTK/b6tRIpEGZXmnbuoCyUL2Yb5ZCgOiofJiYhOPnxf3y4fFptf7Yvx/wxog@CzAcJ4jUqgnSkZzzM/OCFaxkFZPihlvWMbf5FIkGi7ypiB/iya@yC05kI/XOVKqUHgEyrKB5zoEVIp7zMUEIfhdFgtJJwsdfC4aQeEvP1NDplNiZqonddvR20C52lHQzRzs6VEgSSVtkpdOnAEG1xlPEOd5jhlMsGMeHgV5HWg6UjbT@366unugvZd3Al@/nu2Of/hjQqrwObw2EunX6Dw)

As a composed function, `:: [[Char]] -> [[Char]]`, with some helpers.

**Expanded:**

```
n = ['A23456789TJQK': n] // infinitely repeating card number list

filter (...) o permutations // filter the permutations of the argument by ...
  \[[x, s], b, c, d, e] // deconstruct each permutation via pattern matching
    #[p, q, r: _] = ... // define p, q, r as ...
      map snd (...) // the second component of every element in ...
      sort (...) // the sorted list of ...
      zip2 ... [1..] // pairs of ... and the numbers 1, 2, 3, ..
      [... \\ [a, b] <- [b, c, d]] // ... for every pair of number a and house b in [b, c, d]
      (elemIndices a n, b) // pair of the value of that card number and the house
    = ... == e // check ... for equality against the last card
      [..., s] // ..., paired with house s
      snd (span ((<>) x) n) !! (...) // the card number ... places from x
      p + ... // this is kinda obvious
      if(p > q) 0 ... // if p is greater than q, zero, else ...
      if(q < r) (q + r) q // if q is less than r, q + r, else q
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 175 bytes

```ruby
->a{g=->j{j.tr('ATJQKCHS','1:;<=)_z').sum}
e=b=a.sort_by{|i|g[i]}
4.times{|i|(d=g[b[i+1]]-g[b[i]])<13&&(a=b[i,2];e=d)}
[a[e/7],*(b-a).permutation.to_a[e<7?e-1:12-e],a[e/7-1]]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##dVNdb6JAFH33V9yk2aq7AxsBFVvphgwPRB42ZngjpBllVBoVA8OarvW3u3dmrNuk6QuZe849535p3S5eL6vgYj3x0zqwnl5OL7ase90wnc0TGrMu6Q4eHqdB//lvt2837e7cEcEi4HZT1fJ58Xp6K9/WWZmfO54ty51oFNArgnW2yMofgzy39CvP@9OBe3/f4wFGxMkfRVD0z52MZ@LnOCffewuL9@2DqHet5LKs9rasnpGcjn8Ja/AwcCyRE51soen5coBV9u148hmkEQwpzPHBzjncgc/IkJI5I2lEUga2bStIB4bQUGYiw8xZ3rkaziJIYvAYTCKUacNJRJJYZXqMIK3V@qlgJP3/ag@lEaSx8nCoVnuxSvMi4lCChKn9Dmgy16BJQkbD74Yug4RhI8pwEpt2dC8JIy5@jaGr40ls@jQ1fJ1gsIRdazDdsjZw2XsNNME9uRTGMcwiXSMbx2pdOKJLVYe3@SgkVG0c9zA320moSjPrRtrMp54k0VeYRTd1SGEYgx/B6LbbbBSRUJ9hiF19SMVzUpwLHJzbLHJCiROTUI@VXgthZOCUIvyxzRkD9PBxIqOeYZtMqf341iYCCGOnvvL9eET1a8IvhdCo5/pUakjMvKoNgEyoDpt3OodWNnD3u5X4gFVd7YAvqj8C@PbIXxso98ttW4gGmraUGBXlksuqBr4vYFMWhdjDktcFHEu5KfcwgmoFgi83UMmNqAnwoijVH4NvQYpGYnKDZit0GDhQVMc9yArGn44aXo/6iXAM8Ql3vxJ4XwiGXwlGV@LyDw)

A lambda function taking an array of cards as strings

**Commented**

```ruby
->a{g=->j{j.tr('ATJQKCHS','1:;<=)_z').sum}
#helper function converts card to integer, ATJQK to 1:;<= and CHS to )_z then sum ascii values 

e=b=a.sort_by{|i|g[i]}  
#sort according to g. we declare 2 variables here in order to avoid undefined variable error at pre-interpretation check stage.

4.times{|i|(d=g[b[i+1]]-g[b[i]])<13&&(a=b[i,2];e=d)}
#compare each pair of values. if in same suit, store the pair of cards to a
#and the value difference to e. Loop exits with the last suitable pair stored

[a[e/7],*(b-a).permutation.to_a[e<7?e-1:12-e],a[e/7-1]]}
#return array containing the two cards of the same suit in the correct order
#with the correct permutation of the remaining cards (b-a) in the middle
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 41 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ØD;“TJQK”¤io2)1¦€µUḊỤ3R¤œ¿+""Om4%13E
Œ!ÇƇ
```

A monadic Link accepting a list of lists of characters returning a list of all valid arrangements in the same format.

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDBfrRw1zQrwCvR81zD20JDPfSNPw0LJHTWsObQ19uKPr4e4lxkGHlhydfGi/tpKSf66JqqGxK9fRSYqH24@1/z/c7v7/f7SSt4eSjlJIMJAwdgYS5iCul4tSLAA)** (footer formats the result as a grid to avoid the implicit smashing print as performed by the Link's code when run as a full program)

Or see a [test-suite](https://tio.run/##VY6xSsRAFEX79xcuWIjXYpOsZrExvBGHpJD44idYGFas7RabgKU2FmtlsLJUUFYQJmT/I/mR8c12Dszjzp17z0x9tVjced89m@NxuaryshiXL669vo32pu5tvH93n5fD18OwbuML1/ZP7nd/Mjm/SXan8Sn1jztds2n8sP4Yvl81rF10jYoz3f3PiV7UW3tFB/8WabIOdhDep4LKYMYoVQjlBoVFIpgbpEKJaoPKBjNiigWFqB@Oc0s6K0HMOLLIDSWMggNNIaVQxphZpAaHW1SmfIYSIu1yCOcCNVPtcngofEAnI@M/).

I have a sneaking suspicion another approach will be much more terse. I shall have to revisit this challenge later!

...hmm, I had another poke around and got another 41 byter ([test](https://tio.run/##VY7BSsNAEIbv@xaCvcgvtElqEynYMAsuyUHqxHNPXkJfwJv1EhBPetWL9iQeKzS0IqSk77F5kXW2N5fdn3//mfl2y9v5/M65q6Y@mYxH0fFF9/AlO0h63eLnvC@6umm@bf05s@v33iC066dusbWbZXjdLNuX5nf/qNrno121r5zdrGz94QH3b9hVYi7ltNuJFMpD/KpO/y0lnaWPvXEuZhQaQ8JUDKtMIzeIGIlGzCoSr1EYHwakQkbOkvtrYpRowQgJI4NMq4iQk6cJZMoqJQwNYo2zAyoVPkEIgcySb84YEsYyS/4h/wFRQkp/)):

```
O¹*@<74$?€€29%⁽:0%⁴UµṪ_Ḣ%13Ḍ⁼Ụ3R¤œ¿Ɗ
Œ!ÇƇ
```